# Awesome wm panel autohide won't work

Tags: awesome-wm

I wan't to make panel autohide on left side:

```
s.lbox = awful.wibar({ position = "left", screen = s, width = 2, type = "desktop", visible = true })
s.lbox:setup {
        layout = wibox.layout.fixed.vertical,

        {
            layout = wibox.layout.fixed.vertical,
            launcher01,
            launcher02,
            launcher03,
            launcher04,
            launcher05,
            launcher06,
            launcher07,
            launcher08,
            launcher09,
            launcher10,
        }
    }

   s.lbox:connect_signal("mouse::enter", function(w) 
        w:geometry({ width = 32 })
    end)
```

Panel is visible but won't work autohide when i enter mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I've added `height` parameter to the definition and now works:

```
s.lbox = awful.wibar({ position = "left", screen = s, width = 2, height = 760, type = "desktop", visible = true })
```